# Bluetooth Settings Issue After Updating?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, crash, settings, 21.04

I've installed Ubuntu 21.04 in a dual boot configuration alongside an existing installation of Windows 10.

Since using it for about one week I've applied all offered official updates and then restarted.

I paired a set of bluetooth headphones in Ubuntu and then ever since a restart the 'Bluetooth Settings' window either does not load or crashes.

Is Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS more stable vs Ubuntu 21.04 for basic things like 'Bluetooth Settings'?